# WPF - Caliburn Micro Event trigger with control as parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I have a control named `ZoomSlider` which I would like to reference in my `EventTrigger` called via the Caliburn.Micro `Message.Attach` functionality as such:

```
cal:Message.Attach="[Event PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown] = [Action ToggleNew($this, $ZoomSlider)]"
```

The reasoning is that I want then to take action on my `UserControl` *(in this case, slide it open)* when my `ToggleNew` event is raised, but it is impossible to refer to a control in my View from the ViewModel.

How can I refer to the `ZoomSlider` control from the above code ? My first parameter `$this` works perfectly but cannot have the same using the `UserControl`.

Comment: Has my answer worked for you or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that your `ZoomSlider` control is named `myZoomSlider` like this:

```
<ZoomSlider x:Name="myZoomSlider" />
```

Now you can try two things to pass this control to your `ToogleNew` method on your view-model, but first of all you need to define the method `ToogleNew` so that it takes a `ZoomControl` control or any of its super types as a parameter, something like this:

```
public void ToogleNew(ZoomSlider zoomSlider); // you can also pass any additional parameters if you like to
```

Now back to the two methods I told you about:

- Try to pass the control as is like this:

  ```
  cal:Message.Attach="[Event PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown] = [Action ToggleNew(myZoomSlider)]"
  ```
- If the first option didn't work for you, then you can try the following:

  ```
  <ZoomSlider x:Name="myZoomSlider" />
  <Button Content="Toogle">
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
              <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="ToogleNew">
                  <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding ElementName=myZoomSlider}" />
              </cal:ActionMessage>
          </i:EventTrigger>
      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  </Button>
  ```

You can take a look at the [**All about actions**](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions&referringTitle=Documentation) wiki documentation to learn everything and anything regarding actions and action messages.

Comment: Finally made it work but I could not do it via your way for some reason. I had to do a multibinding for the Width. But thanks for the help though. It came in handy for another piece of code I had to write later on